# Facing a Problem in ASP.NET Project (Online Test) while selecting the options(Radiobutton)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, web-applications, radio-button

I am Developing a online test(Multiple choice) in C# asp.net. I have to show only one Question per page. I am using  radiobuttons to select one of the options.
When i click the next button,  options respective to the next Question  bind to the radiobuttons.
The origin of Problem:
I select a radiobutton for one Question and the same radiobutton is selected for all the subsequent questions.
For example, if i select radiobutton3, the radiobutton3 is selected for all the subsequent questions.This issue arise because
i use same 4 radiobutton to bind the options of the all the questions. Please help me how to overcome this problem in C# ASP.NET.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

on your `page_load` reset all radio buttons to their default values (`checked = false`).